# How to change the default layout in Laravel Spark?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, web-frontend, laravel-spark

How can I change the default layout provided by Laravel Spark? I want to integrate theme from something like 
https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469?ref=keenthemes
it would be easy if someone could guide me through the process just so that nothing from the spark end is missed from inclusion.